# LinkedIn REST API OAuth2 401 unauthorized_client error when trying to get access token

Tags: node.js, rest, ember.js, linkedin-api

I'm using Ember.js and Node. I already have json web token based authentication set up and am now trying to use LinkedIn's REST API to get information for my user profiles.

I'm able to redirect my users to the LinkedIn authorization code endpoint (Step 2 in this guide: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2), but I'm getting stuck on Step 3 (Exchange Authorization Code for Access Token). When I make the POST request with the correct parameters, I get a 401 unauthorized_client error no matter how I try and make the request.

I'm making the request directly from my Node server, and using the request module. I've tried including the params as query params, and as part of the body. I've tried adjusting the headers and the url encoding but nothing seems to change the 401 error.

This is the call I need to be making according to the guide:

```
POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.linkedin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code=987654321&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myapp.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&client_id=123456789&client_secret=shhdonottell
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen if you are `POSTing` the correct parameters. You can rather try it with an alternative way. With the authorization code you received in Step 2, use request based service like `POSTMAN` and try getting the response again. If you get it using that it means there has been some error while you are making the request.

Make sure to properly provide the headers.

Even after the `POSTMAN` service if you get an unauthorized response, confirm your `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for 2-legged authentication, the grant_type should always be "client_credentials". Also, you only need to supply the client_id and client_secret as parameters, nothing more. See the [sample in the LinkedIn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context). It looks like you try to do a 3-legged authentication request.